# Yubikey + VMware Horizon + Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: 20.04, yubikey

I use my personal computer with Ubuntu 20.04 to connect to my work Windows 10 client via VMware Horizon (Digital Workspace). I have accounts that use Yubikeys as smart cards. The Yubikeys are attached to my personal machine. When I log into VMware Horizon, I can see the Yubikeys and valid certificates. I can run as on that Windows 10 machine a auth with the Yubikeys. When I RDP from that Windows 10 machine to a remote server, the initial connection allows the use of the Yubikeys but when it tries to log me in interactively, the server cannot use the smart card. This works fine from a Windows laptop from one end to the other. It's not a terrible inconvenience, but if there was a solution, it would be nice to know. Or, if there wasn't and someone could explain to me why, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:
The solution doesnt exist for you right now. Bug fixed after 10.3.5 of VMware tools, which does not appear for Horizon Clients.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/67532

https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/sim/interop_matrix.php#interop&103=&139=

Or, Maybe not. What version of VMware Horizon are you using?
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/sim/interop_matrix.php#interop&569=&139=

The second and third link is a grid describing what VMware Tools correlate to VMware Horizon 7 versions. It appears VMware Horizon 7 version 7.5.0 and above with VMware tools version 10.3.10 and above should have a fix for your problem according to the article on my first link.